# NotifyIteam changed not working properly in recyclerview

Tags: android

When I click on the like button any try to update the count it is updated the first time but next time if I try to increase the count of like it displays the orignal value of the count and after that if I try it display increased value it's working intermittently.

```
    public CategoryListAdapter(Context context, Activity act, ArrayList<CategoryRequest> mData) {
            this.ctx = context;
            this.data = mData;
            this.activity = act;
            //  this.arraylist = new ArrayList<CategoryRequest>();
            //  this.arraylist.addAll(mData);
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(parent.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.row_category, parent, false);
            return new Viewholder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            categoryRequest = getItem(position);

            ((Viewholder) holder).usrname.setText(categoryRequest.getUsr_name());
            ((Viewholder) holder).postname.setText(categoryRequest.getPost_title());
            ((Viewholder) holder).location.setText(categoryRequest.getPost_location());
            ((Viewholder) holder).post_description.setText(categoryRequest.getPost_desc());
            ((Viewholder) holder).like.setText("Good" + "(" + categoryRequest.getPost_good() + ")");
            ((Viewholder) holder).dislike.setText("Bad" + "(" + categoryRequest.getPost_bad() + ")");
            ((Viewholder) holder).comments.setText("Comments" + "(" + categoryRequest.getPost_comment() + ")");


            /**
             * click on good button
             */
            ((Viewholder) holder).like.setTag(position);

            ((Viewholder) holder).like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    TextView text = (TextView) v;

                    if (text.getTag() == v.getTag()) {

                        position_likedislike = Integer.parseInt("" + text.getTag());

                        LikeDislikeRequest likeDislikeRequest = new LikeDislikeRequest();
                        likeDislikeRequest.setLike_lgn_id("1");
                        likeDislikeRequest.setLike_post_id(data.get(Integer.parseInt("" + text.getTag())).getPost_id());
                        likeDislikeRequest.setLike_type("1");

                        HTTPWebRequest.LikeDislikePost(activity, likeDislikeRequest, AppConstants.APICode.likepost, CategoryListAdapter.this);
                    }
                }
            });

            /**
             * click on bad button
             */

            ((Viewholder) holder).dislike.setTag(position);

            ((Viewholder) holder).dislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    TextView text = (TextView) v;

                    if (text.getTag() == v.getTag()) {

                        position_likedislike = Integer.parseInt("" + text.getTag());

                        LikeDislikeRequest likeDislikeRequest = new LikeDislikeRequest();
                        likeDislikeRequest.setLike_lgn_id("1");
                        likeDislikeRequest.setLike_post_id(data.get(Integer.parseInt("" + text.getTag())).getPost_id());
                        likeDislikeRequest.setLike_type("2");

                        HTTPWebRequest.LikeDislikePost(activity, likeDislikeRequest, AppConstants.APICode.dislikepost, CategoryListAdapter.this);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public CategoryRequest getItem(int pos) {
            return data.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public void add(List<CategoryRequest> items) {

            Log.e("data for update", items.get(0).getPost_good());
            Log.e("data for update2", items.get(1).getPost_good());

            int previousDataSize = this.data.size();
            this.data.addAll(items);
            notifyItemRangeInserted(previousDataSize, items.size());
        }


        @Override
        public void apiResponsePostProcessing(String response, int apiCode) {
            Log.d("Login Responce", "response=====" + response);
            if (response != null) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                try {
                    switch (apiCode) {

                        case AppConstants.APICode.likepost:
                            LikeDisLikeResponse likeDisLikeResponse = new LikeDisLikeResponse();
                            likeDisLikeResponse = gson.fromJson(response, LikeDisLikeResponse.class);

                            if (likeDisLikeResponse.getSTATUS().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                                gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                        .registerTypeAdapter(LikeDislikeRequest.class, new LikeDisLikeResponse())
                                        .create();
                                LikeDislikeRequest likeDislikeRequest = gson.fromJson(response, LikeDislikeRequest.class);

                                Log.e("Like count", likeDislikeRequest.getTotalcount());


                                changeLikeCount(position_likedislike, likeDislikeRequest.getTotalcount());

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, likeDisLikeResponse.getMESSAGES().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            break;
                        case AppConstants.APICode.dislikepost:
                            LikeDisLikeResponse likeDisLikeResponse1 = new LikeDisLikeResponse();
                            likeDisLikeResponse1 = gson.fromJson(response, LikeDisLikeResponse.class);

                            if (likeDisLikeResponse1.getSTATUS().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                                gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                        .registerTypeAdapter(LikeDislikeRequest.class, new LikeDisLikeResponse())
                                        .create();
                                LikeDislikeRequest likeDislikeRequest = gson.fromJson(response, LikeDislikeRequest.class);


                                changeDisLikeCount(position_likedislike, likeDislikeRequest.getTotalcount());

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, likeDisLikeResponse1.getMESSAGES().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("OrderListActivity ", "Error in response" + e);
                }
            }
        }

        private void changeLikeCount(int i, String count) {

            data.get(i).setPost_good(count);
            notifyItemChanged(i);

        }

        private void changeDisLikeCount(int i, String count) {

            data.get(i).setPost_bad(count);
            notifyItemChanged(i);


        }
```

Comment: add notifyDataSetChanged(); after notifyItemChanged() and its done.

Comment: why dont you call `setOnClickListener` inside your custom `ViewHolder`? just make it implement `OnClickListener` interface, then call `setOnClickListener(this)`and remove that ugly `setTag` / `getTag` stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Handler:

```
private void changeLikeCount(final int i, final String count) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            data.get(i).setPost_good(count);
            notifyItemChanged(i);
        }
    });
}

private void changeDisLikeCount(final int i, final String count) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            data.get(i).setPost_bad(count);
            notifyItemChanged(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It increase the value in second time but it immediately replace with orignal value and after click it increase the value properly its happen alternativaly